# SQL - Getting category name from SQL table

Tags: sql

I have a table in my database where I store order information. Each order has `OrderID, CategoryName, ProductName`. The `CategoryName` is for knowing which category each product belongs to.

How would I write a SQL query that gets the `categorynames`. I have duplicate `categoryname` in the table, if there are duplicate `categoryname`, then only one `categoryname` of that type.

How does a SQL query for that look like?

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CategoryName 
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: You're welcome - makes your answer posts just that much nicer! (and easier to read)

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can have this syntax as well

```
SELECT CategoryName 
FROM YourTable
Group BY CategoryName
```